# grub rescue error while booting

Tags: grubrescue

I had a dual boot in my laptop Windows 7 & Ubuntu 13.04. I recently deleted the Ubuntu drive but it shows "error: unknown filesystem. grub rescue>" while booting. It is also not detecting any Windows bootable CD. How do I remove this grub rescue error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method is to boot up with your Windows 7 disc, choose System Recovery Options and then click Startup Repair. That should generally remove grub from your master boot record and allow you to boot into Windows normally.

And almost sure you have to make valid Boot CD. The only reason why your Boot CD is bot recognized can be caused by Wrong CD.